# Incorrect branch when adding modules with composer

Tags: 8, drush, version-control, composer

**Edit: [Gist of my complete composer.json](https://gist.github.com/wturrell/1d748af6cbefa584461eb946659eaca4)**

I'm seeing some confusing behaviour with Drupal branch names when adding modules using composer - specifically I seem to be getting the 7.x version of the module rather than 8.x.

This is a composer based setup, **running 8.3.0-rc1** - composer.json includes:

```
"drupal/core": "8.3.0-rc1"
```

My understanding has always been that for modules, whenever you specify the branch in composer, you remove the 7.x- or 8.x from the start.

e.g. I wanted the tagclouds module 8.x-1.x branch, so I did:

```
composer require drupal/tagclouds:1.x
```

Yet what it actually installs is **7.x-1.9+30-dev**

Composer output:

```
 - Installing drupal/tagclouds (dev-1.x 54086ae) Cloning 54086ae717
```

I also ran `drush ups` and got:

> Project was not packaged by drupal.org but obtained from git. You need
>   to enable git_deploy module

So I add and enable git_deploy the same way.

composer.json:

```
"drupal/git_deploy": "2.x"
```

again it installs a 7.x release (7.x-2.2+10-dev)

Any obvious mistakes?

**Other things I've tried:**

- Explicility listing the stability in the version constraints, e.g. `2.x-dev` instead of `2.x`, and `1.x-dev` not `1.x'. (The [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#stability) suggests composer adds this by default though.)
- Using `composer update nothing` to regenerate the composer.lock file

Comment: Are you using the correct packages repo in your repository key?

Comment: Could you post your full composer.json file as well to the question?

Comment: @Kevin: Here's the [full composer.json](https://gist.github.com/wturrell/1d748af6cbefa584461eb946659eaca4)

Comment: Wow, this composer.json is taking over 20 minutes to build and hasn't finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct repository endpoint for Composer. For Drupal 8, it is `https://packages.drupal.org/8`.

Your composer.json file should contain a repository key like so:

```
{ 
    "repositories": { 
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, already got that.

Comment: Actually mine doesn't have a "drupal" key - will add that and check again...

Comment: … didn't make any difference, and in any case, when I checked `git remote -v` from within a couple of modules, they had the correct https://git.drupal.org/project/ repository paths